Permission Issues When Moving Angular Build Files to Target Folder in Maven Multi-Module Project
I'm working on a project where I have both the frontend (Angular) and backend (Spring) codebases in the same repository. I'm trying to build a single fat jar that includes both the Angular and Spring code using the Maven exec plugin.
The build process involves the following steps:
Install the necessary Node modules.
Build the Angular application.
Move the Angular build files to the /public directory.
Package everything into a single fat jar.
The first two steps (installing Node modules and building the Angular application) work flawlessly. However, when it comes to moving the Angular build files to the target folder, I encounter permission issues related to the node_modules directory.
the error looks like :
120 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ SIP-calculator ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] Copying 43184 resources from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  27.146 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-08-21T11:00:00+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) on project SIP-calculator: copying /Users/divyanshdheer/Desktop/sip-calculator-backend/src/main/resources/angular-frontend/node_modules/nice-napi/build/node_gyp_bins/python3 to /Users/divyanshdheer/Desktop/sip-calculator-backend/target/classes/angular-frontend/node_modules/nice-napi/build/node_gyp_bins/python3 failed with FileSystemException: /Users/divyanshdheer/Desktop/sip-calculator-backend/target/classes/angular-frontend/node_modules/nice-napi/build/node_gyp_bins/python3: Operation not permitted -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

My pom.xml looks like :
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-node-packages</id>
                        <phase>
                            validate
                        </phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                                exec
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>
                                npm
                            </executable>
                            <workingDirectory>
                                src/main/resources/angular-frontend
                            </workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>
                                    i
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-ng-locally-then-build</id>
                        <phase>
                            compile
                        </phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                                exec
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>
                                ng
                            </executable>
                            <workingDirectory>
                                src/main/resources/angular-frontend
                            </workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>
                                    build
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

The build configuration for angular looks like :
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../public",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/src/inline-svg/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme.less",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1.2mb",
                  "maximumError": "3mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },

In case I run the command using sudo it works, also in the continuous integration script, the build is successful it seems. But in my local its not working as expected, also In case I run the IntelliJ with root access, the code's working without the need of sudo command.
